# How to check IP addresses a browser is connected to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser, ip, flash

I am playing a Flash-based browser game.

When I connect to the game server is there any way I can check the IP of the server, so I can ping it and check my latency?

I am using Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 with latest Flash player.

Answer (score 1):

This is [easier](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/):
You can list all the network connections opened by using ‘-i’ option.

> lsof -i

You can also use ‘-i4′ or ‘-i6′ to list only ‘IPV4′ or ‘IPV6‘ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of connections used by Chrome with `lsof`:

```
lsof | grep IP | grep chrome
```